# Can we remove the 'See your profile' text in notifications, or make it link to the profile page again?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, notifications

When recieving notifications for earning badges, the text describing the badge still says 'See your profile', a carryover from the old Stack Exchange supercollider:

[image: The page showing the notification bar drop-down]

However, this text is now a part of the link, and therefore takes me to the question/answer that earned the badge, instead of my profile.

Can the text "See your profile" either be removed, or made to link back to our profiles again?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209151/badge-notification-in-achievements-drop-down-links-only-to-relevant-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entire area was overhauled as part of the Top Bar redesign, the 'See your profile' text was removed, and badge notifications now link to the 'Badges' tab on your Profile:

[image: Notification Tray]